# Java, libgdx with Scene2D: creating a level selection menu considering my situation

Tags: java, list, libgdx, scene2d

I am having a problem trying to figure out the correct approach for building a level selection list using these tools. The thing is my levels are actually songs and i have a Song class for these which only contain the songs name as a String and the filename of the music file as a String and then i use a method to load the music file by giving it a Song object when starting a game.

So the thing is I am trying to create a level(song) selection menu for my game, but I am having some problems. I've gotten to a situation where I have created a List of Strings and added this list to a ScrollPane:

```
    private void setupSelectSongStage() {
    selectSongStage = new Stage();

    /* Ignore these, just some old code i tried to do something:
    TextButton returnButton = new TextButton("Return", testSkin);
    TextButton playButtonn = new TextButton("Play", testSkin);

    SongButton song1 = new SongButton(game.erikaSong, testSkin);
    SongButton song2 = new SongButton(game.nopeeHatane, testSkin);
    */

    String[] songNames = {"firstSong", "secondSong", "thirdSong"};
    List songList = new List(testSkin);
    songList.setItems(songNames);

    ScrollPane songsPane = new ScrollPane(songList, testSkin);

    selectSongStage.addActor(songsPane);

}
```

I am trying to figure out how can i modify my code so i would have a some sorta List of all of my Song objects of the game, then create a ScrollPane or something to take the Song objects name into it and when I add the listeners to it it should get the selected Song object that i can pass to the loader when the Song is selected and the game starts.

Any ideas for the correct approach?

Comment: The List is like a drop-down menu. You should make TextButtons and put them in a VerticalGroup inside the ScrollPane. Your stage needs a viewport, and it's better to create a single SpriteBatch for your whole app that you can pass into any Stage constructors, since SpriteBatch is a heavy object (allocates a bunch of memory and compiles a shader).

Comment: Thank you! The VerticalGroup class was the thing i was looking for!